# Django models: Is object descendant of another object?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a model **Category**. Category can have one **supercategory** and multiple **subcategories** - like tree structure. All of them are Category objects.

I'm trying to create a method which tells me if self is a **descendant** of given category. For now, it can say if it's a child but I want to detect grandchild, grandgrandchild etc. too.

Do you know how to make it work? Is there some built-in tool for this?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
    supercategory = models.ForeignKey('Category',null=True,blank=True)

    def is_subcategory(self,category):
        if self.supercategory == category:
             return True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: For a structure like this you should use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using recursion. 
Recursion is a general concept in programming, basically it's when a function is calling itself.

Here you could do:

```
def is_subcategory(self,category):
    if self.supercategory is None:
         return false
    return (self.supercategory == category or 
            self.supercategory.is_subcategory(category))
```

The dangerous thing with this, is an infinite stack calls if there is a loop in the categories parenting.

Comment: Oh thanks, recursion didn't come to my mind. Nice solution.